# Sourcemap is off for vite/vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vite, source-maps

In vue/vite/rails stack sourcemap is completely off.
Devtool showing incorrect line on error/debug.
Can figure out what exactly causing issue.

vite.config.ts:

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import rubyPlugin from "vite-plugin-ruby";
import vuePlugin from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import {nodePolyfills} from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";
import * as requirePlugin from "vite-plugin-require";
import sassGlobImportPlugin from "vite-plugin-sass-glob-import";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        sourcemap: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ...
        },
        extensions: [".js", ".es6", ".ts",  ".json", ".vue"]
    },
    plugins: [
        rubyPlugin(),
        nodePolyfills(),
        vuePlugin({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    whitespace: "preserve"
                }
            }
        }),
        requirePlugin.default(),
        sassGlobImportPlugin(),
    ],
    clearScreen: false,
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ["crypto"]
    }
});
```

Example Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Home Page
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Home",
        mounted() {
            throw Error("This is error");
        },
    };
</script>
```

This is what it showing me in devtool:

[image]

[image]

Expect to show correct error line in devtool

Comment: Found issue but didn't find solution. Problem with `vite-plugin-require`